# Facebook authentication activity from class for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have  class A that can upload photo to facebook, I don't want class A to be in activity, but I know that facebook authentication must be an activity. How can I call this activity from my class and make this activity return me authenticated Facebook instance ?

Comment: Background processes,threads?

Comment: yes, but when the authentication finished how can I return to my class the created Facebook instance

Comment: You can create an `interface` and set your listener.Whenever your authentication comes you can call your listener method. After that you can implement your listener to your activity.

Comment: Can somebody give an example how to do this ?